# How to change default home icon

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

My default app theme is  Redmond and I want to use a different home icon color via bread crumb.

I added  hot-sneaks theme to the pom.xml  in order to use a different color.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>hot-sneaks</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

How can I change the home icon in  DefaultMenuItem ?

```
private void createHomeMenu() {
    // Create home menuItem
    DefaultMenuItem home = new DefaultMenuItem();
    home.setIcon( ?? );
    home.setAjax(true);

    breadCrumbModel.addElement(home);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces use [jQuery themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for styling UI. All of the used icons in Primefaces are from there. Thus, you can select satisfied icon from [jquery icons](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/).

```
public class BreadcrumbView {

    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
        item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
        item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
        model.addElement(item);

    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

However, You can specify a custom icon by using css style class :

```
public class BreadcrumbView {

    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
        item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
        item.setIcon("xlogo");
        model.addElement(item);

    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

and load the image located at `resources/default/images/icons` folder like this:

```
.xlogo {
    background: url('#{resource['default:images/icons/x_logo.png']}') no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```